# Need command line / TCP midi player

Tags: byte, midi, playback

I'm making a MIDI application with adobe AIR and in order that I might play dynamic real time(ish) output I would like either:

A program which accepts raw midi data on std input and plays it

or

An API which I can use to play raw midi byte data

I've looked at the Java sound API and others but they doesn't seem to have functionality for playing a raw stream of bytes. If anyone knows anything similar which accepts input in a format other than MIDI, I'd like to hear it because I can easily translate my MIDI data if needed! Thanks in advance